# pure css way to fit images across a row

Tags: css

Is there a pure css way to make images fit in a row across a container with variable size?

I have a row of images I want to fit.

There are 2 ways I know of to fit images in a row. If I set the image width as a percent ie, `width: 20%`, then if the screen is wide then the images becomes very large or if the display is small the images becomes very small. If I set the images as absolute width ie, `width: 100px;`, then the images are shown with the size I want it to. But the container isn't totally filled and there's unseemly left over space at the right.

Right now I'm using javascript to adjust the percentage width based on the user screen width.

Is there a pure css method of controlling the way that images are shown, such that if the screen is wide more images fit into a row rather than blowing them up but still ensuring that all the images fit snuggly into the container with no left over space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using media queries like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 600px)
  img
    width 50%

@media all and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 900px)
  img
    width 33.3333%

@media all and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1050px)
  img
    width 25%

@media all and (max-width: 1910px) and (min-width: 1600px)
  img
    width 16.6667%
```

I think there's a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add float property to each of your image container (float: left). see http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0407.htm

Comment: This won't handle the "fit snuggly into the container with no left over space" part.